# Scraping a dynamically loaded table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My code could return values of first two  tags, but the behind won't in per  tag.

HTML:
[image]

My code:
import bs4 as bs
import requests

```
resp = requests.get('https://q.stock.sohu.com/cn/bk_4401.shtml')
resp.encoding = 'gb2312'
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
tab_sgtsc_list = soup.find('table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')

for tab_sgtsc in tab_sgtsc_list:
    print('**************************************')
    print(tab_sgtsc.find_all('td')[0].text)
    print(tab_sgtsc.find_all('td')[1].text)
    print(tab_sgtsc.find_all('td')[2].text)
    print(tab_sgtsc.find_all('td')[3].text)
    print('**************************************')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Answer (score 2):

The table is rendered dynamically by `JavaScript` so you won't get much from pure `HTML`.

However, `selenium` and `pandas` come to the rescue!

Required:

- [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)
- [selenium](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-install/)
- `pip install pandas`

Here's how:

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://q.stock.sohu.com/cn/bk_4401.shtml")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.tableMSB'))
).text.replace("点击按代码排序查询", "").split()

table = [element[i:i + 12] for i in range(0, len(element), 12)]
pd.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0]).to_csv("your_table_data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have run your code many times. It successfully returned data twice, but in most cases it would return 'Nan' in these columns behind the first two.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Can you share more details? What does "these columns behind the first two" mean? There are many columns? Do all have NaN? How do you run a script? Do you have an error?

Comment: I add 'print(pd.concat(df))' in the last, and the result is
0           605060  联德股份  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
1           605068  明新旭腾  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
2           605066  天正电气  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
3           300906   日月明  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
4           300907  康平科技  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
..             ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ..   ...  ...    ...  ...  ...
.

Comment: Have you checked the `csv` file? That's what I'm showing as *final* result. Open it using Excel or OpenOffice. By the way, adding `print(pd.concat(df))` as the last line doesn't change anything on my end. See this - https://imgur.com/a/iXb0URx

Comment: In the csv file, there is no result from the '当前价' column(title) to '昨收盘'.

Comment: @bqlong I've updated the answer, try with this one.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I've got all the values in the table in other way.